# set jquery-ui dialog content to the dialog size

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am having jquery-ui dialog as in 
 [here](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/creating-a-windows-like-interface-with-jquery-ui/)

The problem is, on specifing some contents and then pressing the create button the contents needs to fill the entire dialog, but it's calculating it's own width and height and positioning it only in a part of the dialog.
I Tried by giving

```
width:100%;
```

to the id of the content holder in css but it doesnt work.

Screenshot:
[image]

CSS:

```
.ui-dialog .ui-dialog-content { position: relative; border: 0; padding: .5em 1em; background: none; overflow: auto; zoom: 1; width:auto;/*height: auto;*/}
```

Can anybody help me where i am going wrong?

Cheers
Jeev

Comment: Can you show us the code, or link an example?

Comment: i am new to this , i dont know how to create a fiddle , can u suggest me how to add a screenshot? so that can give u the idea of what's happening?

Comment: We need to see the html, or script that creates it, in order to see what's wrong.  A screenshot will be no use.

Comment: There's too much of code and i myself am confused which one does what.

Answer (score 0):

saw the link you gave there.

i haven't got the id of appearing div.give some id if its not there.and then apply following css.

```
#id_of_dialogue{
height: 430px;
width: 368px;
top: 80px;
left: 324px;
}
```

Comment: appearing div in the sense the id of the dialog which holds the contents?? well it's not static, it changes for every dialog it's mentioned as  $('#' + div_id).dialog({ width: 'auto',         height: 'auto',});